# Products database Design: Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model or No SQL or another alterative models?

Tags: magento, database-design, product, entity-attribute-value, nosql

Please, What is the best model to design and create an products database if I'm planning on having many products in the database: is Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model (By using Magento) or No SQL database or another alternative models?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049159/alternatives-to-entity-attribute-value-eav)

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons for both models:

**Pros** for **EAV(Entity_Attribute_Value)**:

- Facilitates a generic architecture (easy to add|remove attributes)
- Relatively easy to implement

**Cons** for **EAV**

- Slow, resource consuming

  ### - Not scalable

**Pros** for **NoSQL**

- Fast, increased performance, easy to get all the needed information, usually will be stored in the same document.
- Easy to scale

**Cons** for **NoSQL**

- This is a hell to implement, when the times comes to manage generic stuff.

In conclusion I will suggest to choose `NoSQL` the biggest pro that I see is `scalability`.

Comment: Please, what do you think about integrating MongoDB ( NoSQL database) in Magento? @Alexandru Olaru

Comment: There are some tentatives to use MongoDB with Magento, one of them you can find at: https://github.com/Smile-SA/mongogento, personally i think it will depend on the `magento` core functionalities that you need, the more functionalities the bigger the risk something wasn't adapted yet... It's very risky, I wouldn't do that in a production site unless I did tone of tests on development environments...