# MySQL Products properties table design

Tags: mysql, database-design

for a current customer project, i've developed a CMS that stores **products**.

Products are entries that have some properities like *title*, *text* & etc.
However, some clients want to have different properties like **price**, **color** & etc.

I try to make my code **as generic as possible** so i don't want to modify the code
for each customer.

My Question:
**How can i design such a database, that a product can have infinite, multiple properties?**
**How to create/generate forms for such a different design?**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is a FAQ, you may start here and follow the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768074/extendable-database-schema-how-to-store-the-extendable-attribute-values/6768919#6768919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products( product_id INT, product_name VARCHAR, ... );
CREATE TABLE product_properties( product_id INT, property_name VARCHAR, property_value VARCHAR );
```

---

The first table contains one product per row with their unique ID and their common properties

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |      name       |   other common properties...
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      apple      |   ...
|  2   |      bentley    |
|  3   |      ...        |
|  ... |      ...        |
```

The second table relates each product to its non-common properties:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id   |    property_name   |    property_value    |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1   |    color           |    red               |
|  1   |    size            |    large             |
|  2   |    wheel count     |    4                 |
|  2   |    top speed       |    200               |
|  2   |    airbags         |    yes               |
|  ... |    ...             |    ...               |
```

You get a product's information with two queries, first you get the common properties:

```
SELECT product_name, ... FROM products WHERE product_id = 2
```

then the non-common properties:

```
SELECT property_name, property_value FROM product_properties WHERE product_id = 2
```

Comment: Could you please extend your answer with some example data and a few queries? It would be very helpful, THANK YOU

Comment: @HerrKaleun there you go. need more info?

Comment: your design has a lot of redundancy.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple and understandable to show the concept. It can be optimized a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a table for properties and a table for owning a property, so your tables schema will be like this:

Products(*id*,title,text,...)

Properties(*id*,name)

Product_Properties(*ProductId*, *PropertyId*, value)

So you define list of desired properties on property table and assign them to products by inserting tuples in Product_Properties. Consider You have 2 products(A and B) which in your case, have these properties: height, color, price as this:

```
A: 180, Red, 200$
B: 170, Blue, 270$
```

Your tables will have these tuples:

Products(*id*,title,text):

```
(1,"A","desc1")
(2,"B","desc2")
```

---

Properties(*id*,name)

```
(1,"height")
(2,"color")
(3,"price")
```

---

Product_Properties(*ProductId*, *PropertyId*, value)

```
(1,1,"180")
(2,1,"179")
(1,2,"Red")
(2,1,"Blue")
(1,3,"200")
(2,3,"270")
```

---

---

And here is a query which retrieves products whit a 'price' equal to '200':

```
SELECT P.title
FROM Product P,Properties Pr,Product_Properties PP
WHERE  P.id=PP.ProductId AND PP.PropertyId=Pr.id AND Pr.name='height' AND PP.value='200'
```

Comment: Good, however with this method you would have 1 price for all variations of the product. Many businesses will need to charge a different price for different properties i.e. a size:large item may be more expensive than size:small item.